# Is there any difference between "@empty" and "@null"?

Tags: android, android-resources

While digging through some theme, i have found two interested values an attribute can have:

```
<item name="android:background">@null</item>
<item name="android:background">@empty</item>
```

As far as i know, a widget that will apply a style with `android:background` that equals `null` will call a method matches `android:background` attribute and pass in to this method `null` as a parameter. **So What happens when we write `@empty` ?** **What is the difference between `@empty` and `@null` ?**

Comment: `@empty` basically means "null, and leave it null instead of using default value". For example, some `View`s will set their own backgrounds if they get a null value from the XML attributes. `@empty` would indicate that it really should be null. Do note, however, that the `View` itself has to be properly coded to account for `@empty` values; i.e., it's not going to work everywhere for every attribute.

Comment: Having read this more closely, I should also mention that that's not quite how `android:background` would be processed. `@null` would simply cause the `background` value to be removed from the resulting attribute array. In order to set only those values specified in XML – rather than blindly setting every possible styleable property – `View` loops over that resulting `TypedArray`, so a `setBackground()` call would be skipped altogether for `@null`. On the other hand, `@empty` will keep `background` in the array, with an explicit null value, in which case `setBackground(null)` would be called.

Comment: @MikeM.  So all depends on how view was coded ? if we want, we can make `setBackground(null)` be called for `@null` and be skipped altogether for `@empty` in an own view ?

Comment: Sure, but there would be no point in calling `setBackground(null)` at all, unless the superclass is setting a default upon null, which most don't. I was just describing how it would end up being handled in the `View` class in particular, and the `setBackground(null)` call there is actually pointless because `View`'s background is already null by default; i.e., it's initialized to null. `@empty` wasn't added until API level 22, which is why it has confusing semantics and causes redundancies like that in older code. It was tacked onto a design where null was signified by an absent entry...

Comment: ...rather than an explicit value. Anyhoo, if you have a look at the `TypedArray` class, you'll see a handful of methods that recognize and account for `@empty`, particularly [`hasValueOrEmpty()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/TypedArray#hasValueOrEmpty(int)). However, if you can skip the call for both, you don't have to mess with `@empty` at all, and can simply check if `TypedArray#getDrawable()` returns null before making the call.

Comment: Lastly, you shouldn't really have to handle the `android:background` attribute directly. `View` has already processed it by the time your constructor runs, so you can just check `getBackground()`. I was only using it as a general example of how you'd handle such an attribute.